# Решение задачи проходит 5/7 тестов

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, рефакторинг

#### Описание задачи:

На старой заброшенной базе геодезистов вы нашли код, который возвращает секретные послания, зашифрованные среди географических данных. Скрипт содержит несколько синтаксических ошибок и кажется работает очень медленно. Ваша задача - привести его в порядок.

#### Формат ввода:

```
const data = [  
    {  
        geometry: [10, 20],  
        text: ’James’  
    },  
    {  
        geometry: [20, 40],  
        text: ’Bond’  
    },  
    {  
        geometry: [5, 40],  
        text: ’Bond’  
    }  
];  
const dictionary = [’James’, ’Bond’];
```

#### Формат вывода

`Bond James Bond`

#### Примечания:

В файле [task.js](https://gist.github.com/alt-j/0f30495b549cddcab8b95ae76bcd9b49#file-task-js) описан метод, который принимает на вход два аргумента - `data` и `dictionary`. В переменной `data` передается массив объектов вида:

```
{  
    geometry: [number, number];  
    text: string;  
}
```

В переменной `dictionary` передается массив строк - слова, которые мы умеем расшифровывать.
`dictionary: string[];`

Чтобы получить секретное сообщение, требуется отсортировать все объекты из массива `data` по первой координате из поля `geometry` по возрастанию, а затем собрать в строку все поля `text` из отсортированного массива.

К сожалению, сообщение закодировано на иностранном языке, а переводчик знает только слова, заданные в переменной `dictionary`. Поэтому если в поле `text` встречается слово, которого нет в массиве `dictionary`, сообщение невозможно расшифровать.

Программа должна вернуть полученное сообщение или строку `"Unreadable message"`(в случае, если сообщение содержит слова, которых нет в словаре).

Решение необходимо предоставить в виде исправленного модуля.

#### Мое решение:

```js
module.exports = function (inputData, inputDictionary) {
    inputData = inputData
        .sort((firstItem, secondItem) => firstItem.geometry[0] - secondItem.geometry[0])
        .map(item => item.text);
    return inputData.every(txt => inputDictionary.includes(txt))
        ? inputData.join(' ')
        : 'Unreadable message';
};
```

> P.S. Не могу понять, что не так в отрефакторенном коде. Хотелось, чтобы кто-то дал наводку, в какую сторону смотреть.

Answer (score 1):

Если заменить символы одиночной кавычки на любые другие корректные в JS, то код у Вас вполне рабочий:

```js
function exports(inputData, inputDictionary) {
  inputData = inputData.sort((firstItem, secondItem) => firstItem.geometry[0] - secondItem.geometry[0]);
  return inputData.every(obj => inputDictionary.includes(obj.text)) ?
    inputData.map(item => item.text).join(' ') :
    'Unreadable message';
}
const dictionary = ['James', 'Bond'];

const data = [
  { geometry: [10, 20], text: 'James' },
  { geometry: [20, 40], text: 'Bond' },
  { geometry: [5, 40], text: 'Bond' }
];
console.log(exports(data, dictionary));

const wrongData = [
  { geometry: [10, 20], text: 'James' },
  { geometry: [20, 40], text: 'Bond' },
  { geometry: [5, 40], text: 'Ivan' }
];
console.log(exports(wrongData, dictionary));
```

Comment: Это из постановки такие кавычки. Уверен, при тестировании применяются валидные для js. Да, свой код проверял на работоспособность в IDE. Но так и не выяснил, почему проходят не все тесты :) Ну что же, буду думать еще. Спасибо